# extraneous end if in .dep.inc file

Tags: jenkins, netbeans, makefile, netbeans-7, preprocessor

I am giving a job to Jenkins to build binaries for my code through `make file` . It is showing error of extraneous end if in .dep.inc file,I tried to change the configuration of net beans.

This file is getting generated from auto generated make file in net beans. In net beans it is compiling but in Jenkins it is showing error.*

```
# dependency checking support
.depcheck-impl:
    @echo "# This code depends on make tool being used" >.dep.inc
    @if [ -n "${MAKE_VERSION}" ]; then \
        echo "DEPFILES=\$$(wildcard \$$(addsuffix .d, \$${OBJECTFILES}))" >>.dep.inc; \
        echo "ifneq (\$${DEPFILES},)" >>.dep.inc; \
        echo "include \$${DEPFILES}" >>.dep.inc; \
        echo "endif" >>.dep.inc; \
    else \
        echo ".KEEP_STATE:" >>.dep.inc; \
        echo ".KEEP_STATE_FILE:.make.state.\$${CONF}" >>.dep.inc; \
    fi
```

Comment: I am getting error like .dep.inc:3: *** extraneous `endif'.  Stop. in jenkins build. Please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: Please feel free to ask any doubts to help me to find a root cause of build fail.

Comment: # This code depends on make tool being used
@if [ -n "${MAKE_VERSION}" ]; then  
DEPFILES= $$(wildcard  $$(addsuffix .d,  $${OBJECTFILES}))  
ifneq ( $${DEPFILES},)
include  $${DEPFILES}
endif

Comment: Please update your question and show the contents of the `.dep.inc` file (please use proper formatting when you paste in the contents).

Comment: when I am giving make  with makefile command,it is having dependency on the above code.It is generating .dep.inc file with the below code.                                                                         
# This code depends on make tool being used
endif
DEPFILES=$(wildcard $(addsuffix .d, ${OBJECTFILES}))
ifneq (${DEPFILES},)
include ${DEPFILES}
endif

Comment: Please update your question (that is, click the edit link and add the info into the question, properly formatted (indent lines with 4 spaces to quote code) then save).  Putting this info into the comments doesn't work since the formatting (exactly what is on each line) is critical and comments have no line formatting available.

Answer (score 1):

you are using BASH syntax instead of Makefile. One option could be to use the conditional structure of Makefile:
[Conditional Parts of Makefiles](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_7.html)

Another way is to define the whole BASH instruction in the same line, like that:

```
if [ <condition>]; then <action1>; else <action2>; fi
```

In Makefile, each line of a target could be a SHELL, but you should not split them.

Finally, you can use the "define" environment to insert BASH code:

```
define <name>=
<BASH code>
<...>
<name>: ; @$(value <name>)
.ONESHELL
```

I hope you find it useful!